# StackPanel visibility depending on Combobox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I want to have a StackPanel who's visibility should be depending on a Combobox selection. Unfortunatly the XAML below does not work.

I found a solution with a new property which will be set on the PropertyChanged event of the Combobox selection, though I would prefer a strict XAML solution for this.

Any hints on how to solve this?

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label>Picture in Picture function</Label>
    <ComboBox Name="cbPictureInPicture" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PictureInPictureCodeList, Mode=OneWay}" DisplayMemberPath="CodeText"
        SelectedValuePath="CodeID" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=PictureInPicture, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbPictureInPicture, Path=IsSelected.CodeText}" Value="Yes">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    <Label>Picture in Picture is used</Label>
    (...)
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may perhaps rewrite the same as

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbPictureInPicture, Path=SelectedItem.CodeText}" Value="Yes">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

assuming the combobox is bound to a collection whose item has CodeText property. so SelectedItem.CodeText will point to the same.

additionally it may not be required to set `<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />` as it is the default value. it does not have any effect in this case just some extra line of code which can be removed.

Comment: I used IsSelected instead of SelectedItem. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a converter and bind directly to the `PictureInPicture` property:

```
<StackPanel  Visibility="{Binding PictureInPicture, Converter={StaticResource myVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <Label>Picture in Picture is used</Label>
    (...)
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I tried this but the converter only gets called while opening the view?

Comment: @MwBakker, probably Binding mode is set to OneTime, replace it with `Binding PictureInPicture, Converter={StaticResource myVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay` and it should be called every time `PictureInPicture` changes, assuming it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score -2):

1. Create flags and pass this flag in stackpanel visibility converter.
2. On the basis of flag in converter make decision stackpanel visible/hide whatever
3. Set this flat in comboBox selection change event if selected value as per your requirement.